# Show that the function $f(x,y)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ is continuous at $(0,0)$ but $f_x,f_y$ do not exist at $(0,0)$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

> Show that the function $f(x,y)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ is continuous at $(0,0)$ but $f_x,f_y$ do not exist at $(0,0)$.

MY ATTEMPT:
I completed the first part of the question where it asked to prove the continuity at $(0,0)$.
I also found out $f_x$ and $f_y$.
\begin{equation}
f_x(0,0)= \lim_{h\to 0}(\frac{f(0+h,0)-f(0,0)}{h}=(h/h)=1
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
f_y(0,0)= \lim_{k\to 0}(\frac{f(0,0+k)-f(0,0)}{k}=(k/k)=1
\end{equation}.

My doubt is how can we show that $f_x(0,0)$ and $f_y(0,0)$ do not exist.  Is it when it is undefined or when $f_x(0,0)$ and $f_y(0,0) \neq 0$?

Comment: $\sqrt {h^{2}+0^{2}}=|h|$ and $lim \frac {|h|} h$ does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the symmetry, it is enough to check for any one of $f_{x}$ or $f_{y}$. Using the definition of the partial derivative.

$$\begin{aligned}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sqrt{h^{2}}-0}{h}\\ &= \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{|h|}{h}\end{aligned}$$

It can be clearly seen that the limit does not exist. Approaching from $0^{+}$ gives $1$ while from $0^{-}$ gives $-1$, and hence $f_{x}$ and $f_{y}$ do not exist at the origin.